# Tkinter GUI Bug Displays Character Life Points Instead of Description in Python Graphic Adventure Game

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm new to Python programming and currently working on a simple graphic adventure video game. I decided to use Tkinter as the GUI framework for my game, aiming to create something decent. However, I've encountered a small but frustrating issue that I can't seem to solve.

In my game, players can choose between three characters. To facilitate this, I created a separate window that opens when a button is clicked in the main game window. This character selection window features a carousel-like display, showcasing a photo, name, and description for each character. I've implemented the basic structure of the carousel and managed to display the names and descriptions. However, the problem arises when the first character's life points are shown instead of their description. I've checked the corresponding class for any overlooked mistakes, but everything seems to be correctly written.

If you can provide assistance in resolving this issue, I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you!

Here is the class that displays the name, description, life, damage, fortune, and special ability of the character:

```
class Naturalista(Personaggio):
    def __init__(self, nome, descrizione, vita, attacco, fortuna):
        super().__init__(nome, vita, descrizione, attacco, fortuna)
    
    def abilita_speciale(self):
        print(f"{self.nome} attiva la sua abilità speciale!")
        self.vita += 10  # Aumenta i punti vita del personaggio
        self.fortuna += 1  # Aumenta la fortuna
```

This is a screen of the window for character selection:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zItWX.png)

And here is the relevant code:

```
#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#
#FINESTRA SELEZIONE PG
#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#
def selezione_pg():
    global selezione_pg_w, frame_container, btn_personaggi

    selezione_pg_w = tk.Toplevel(root)
    selezione_pg_w.title("Z'luh-Makta, L'Abisso - Selezione Personaggio")
    selezione_pg_w.geometry("800x500+400+200")
    selezione_pg_w.configure(bg="black")
    
    #frame container
    frame_container = tk.Frame(selezione_pg_w, bg="black")
    frame_container.pack(pady=20)

    # Crea un pulsante per ogni personaggio disponibile
    for i, personaggio in enumerate(personaggi_disponibili):
        btn_personaggio = tk.Button(frame_container, text=f"{personaggio.nome}\n\n{personaggio.descrizione}", font=("Courier New", 10, "bold"), cursor="pirate", bg="black", fg="white", command=lambda i=i: seleziona_personaggio(i))
        btn_personaggio.grid(row=0, column=i, padx=10)
        btn_personaggi.append(btn_personaggio)       

    # Pulsante "Chiudi"
    btn_chiudi = tk.Button(selezione_pg_w, text="Chiudi", font=("Courier New", 10, "bold"), cursor="pirate", bg="black", fg="white", command=selezione_pg_w.destroy)
    btn_chiudi.pack(pady=10)
    btn_chiudi["state"] = "normal"
```

Here are the window settings, including an iteration that creates a button for each character and a button to close the window.

I attempted to add parentheses to the f-string for the character description as follows:

```
btn_personaggio = tk.Button(frame_container, text=f"{personaggio.nome}\n\n{personaggio.descrizione()}", font=("Courier New", 10, "bold"), cursor="pirate", bg="black", fg="white", command=lambda i=i: seleziona_personaggio(i))
```

However, this resulted in an empty window.

Then, I tried modifying the **str** method of the class by adding the following code:

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.descrizione
```

Unfortunately, this did not produce any changes.

P.S. I apologize for any errors in my English. I don't have much practice writing in this language.

Comment: In the Naturalista class the parameters escrizione, vita are swapped when passing up to the parent class. Looks likely to be the problem. To avoid this kind of error in python you could use named parameters instead of order dependent parameters. eg `Person(name=nome, description=desc, ...)`

Comment: Thank you patthoyts! I absolutely hadn't noticed it,  I was driving myself crazy over such a trivial mistake ahah

Comment: Why not answer your own question? And post a [mre].